# Returning a value from user information and display it in an input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I want to check if the user is logged in or not, if the user is logged in then, their first name should be returned to the input and the input should be disabled when there is a value inside.

> ```
>   <label for="firstName" className="col-form-label-sm">First Name</label>
>     <input type="text" className="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="John" name="first_name" onChange={this.props.handleChange} value={this.props.first_name} disabled={this.props.disabled}/>
> ```

here is the state

```
state = {
    first_name: !this.props.getUserDataLogin.data.first_name ? "" : this.props.getUserDataLogin.data.first_name,
}
```

this is handleChange

```
    handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })
}
```

edit: I also have the

```
componentWillReceiveProps = (nextProps) => {

        if(nextProps.getUserDataLogin.data !== this.props.getUserDataLogin.data){
        var { data } = nextProps.getUserDataLogin
        this.setState({
            first_name: data.first_name,
            disabled: true,
            createNewAccount: false,
            me: true
        })
    }
}
```

The problem is, I do get the value and it is displayed in the input, but it is not disabled. It becomes disabled when I reload the page though. I have missed something here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

componentWillReceiveProps Is deprecated due to side effects and not recommended to use. Check this blog for more details

https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html

But still you can achieve what you want without componentWillReceiveProps.

Since onChange event handler function handleChange is declared in Parent component and passed as a props to child and whenever onChange happens the child component gets called if you do setState in there so your constructor gets called every time this component is called.

```
constructor(props){
   super(props);
      this.state = {
          disabled: !this.props.getUserDataLogin.data.first_name ? false : true,
          first_name: !this.props.getUserDataLogin.data.first_name ? "" : this.props.getUserDataLogin.data.first_name
      }
 }

 <input type="text" className="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="John" name="first_name" onChange={this.props.handleChange} value={this.props.first_name} disabled={this.state.disabled}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

add componentWillReceiveProps, then set to your props to state.

```
constructor(){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    disabled: this.props.disabled
  };
}
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (nextProps.disabled !== this.state.disabled) {
    this.setState({disabled: nextprops.disabled});
  } 
}

<input type="text" className="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="John" name="first_name" onChange={this.props.handleChange} value={this.props.first_name} disabled={this.state.disabled}/>
```

Comment: I have edited my question and added my componentWillReceiveProps

Comment: change your input disabled into disabled={this.state.disabled} @eibersji

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I do not know where you define your state. I am assuming the first `state` expression is  using ES7 syntax and you are passing the props properly. Then you should do like this

```
  constructor(props) {
    // if you do not include this this.props will be undefined here
    super(props); 
    this.state = {
      name: props.auth ? "First Name" : "",
    }
  }
```

where auth is your authentication to decide whether your user is logged in or not.

Other scenario might be your props are not passed when the component in instantiated. The safe way is doing in the componentDidMount Lifecycle.

Here is the demo. https://codesandbox.io/s/kx2x4r3185

Comment: I have editted my question and added componentWillReceiveProps

Comment: componentWillReceiveProps is deprecated but you can still use UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps(). Otherwise, just use componentDidMount or shouldComponentUpdate and compared the nextState with previousState.